# Tell child directive to act after a parent directive has done DOM actions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

Let's say we have some nested directives:

```
<big-poppa>
  <baby-bird></baby-bird>
</big-poppa>
```

And let's say that `big-poppa` wants to create a component that all of his children directives can share. It would be nice to put it in the controller, but this component needs the DOM, so it needs to be build in the link function.

Then let's say the `baby-bird` component wants to read from component. Maybe it wants to listen to events from it, maybe send it a command or two. The challenge is that controllers fire down the dom (first parent, then child), and post-link methods fire the other direction, so the execution order looks like this:

1. bigPoppa controller
2. babyBird controller
3. babyBird link
4. bigPoppa link

The fact that the parent's `link` method fires after the child's is the cause of an intra-directive communication challenge for me. I want the parent to build the shared DOM component, but DOM construction should happen in a link function. The parent therefore builds the component after any children

I can solve this with a timeout (gross), or a promise (complex/non-idiomatic?). Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8xF3Z/4/

```
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);


    app.directive('bigPoppa', function($q){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: function($scope){
                console.log('bigPoppa controller');
                var d = $q.defer()
                $scope.bigPoppaLinkDeferred = d
                $scope.bigPoppaLink = d.promise
            },
            link: function(scope, el, attrs){
                console.log('bigPoppa link');
                scope.componentThatNeedsDom = { el: el, title: 'Something' };
                scope.bigPoppaLinkDeferred.resolve()
            }
        }
    });

    app.directive('babyBird', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: function(){ console.log('babyBird controller'); },
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, bigPoppaController){
                console.log('babyBird link');

                // console.log('poppa DOM component', scope.componentThatNeedsDom); // Not yet defined, because the parent's link function runs after the child's

                // setTimeout(function(){ console.log('poppa DOM component', scope.componentThatNeedsDom); }, 1); // Works, but gross

                scope.bigPoppaLink.then(function(){
                  console.log('poppa DOM component', scope.componentThatNeedsDom);
                }); // works, but so complex!

            }
        }
    });

    console.log(''); // blank line
```

Lots of background here, but my question is this simple:

> Is there a clean way to do behavior in a child directive after a parent's directive has run its post-link function?

Maybe a way of using `priority`, or the `pre` and `post` link methods?

Comment: The `Priority` won't help in parent-child relationship. I believe the `preLink` is what you are looking for. Move the `scope.componentThatNeedsDom` declaration into `preLink`, but resolve the promise in `postLink` as you do currently.

Comment: That's the direction I'm pursuing now, I think it's the right track. Thanks for the pointer, @runTarm. I remember reading some warning about using the `el` in a compile or pre-link phase, but it seems correct here.

Comment: Yeah, the element could be used in the pre-link phase, but you need to be careful since controllers/links of children directives haven't been run yet.

As long as you haven't modified any DOM that contains children directives or binding, it should be fine.

Comment: What's your actual use case? If you're doing a lot of DOM manipulation, I wonder if there is a way that uses more standard Angular templates/bindings/events?

Comment: parent directive instantiates a pair of slickgrids, one starts empty and is meant to hold pinned columns. children directives add features, one feature per directive (group, context menu, custom grid headers, filtering, sorting) to both grids using a combination of scope and require controller communication. Would be a lot to go into detail, but that's the high-level.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of achieving this is to use plain Angular scope events to communicate from the parent linking function to the child.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('bigPoppa', function($q){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){
      scope.$broadcast('bigPoppa::initialised',  {el: el, title: 'Something'});
    }
  }
});

app.directive('babyBird', function(){
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      scope.$on('bigPoppa::initialised', function(e, componentThatNeedsDom) {
        console.log('poppa DOM component in bird linking function', componentThatNeedsDom); 
      }); 
    }
  }
});
```

This can be seen working at http://jsfiddle.net/michalcharemza/kerptcrw/3/

This way has the benefits:

- Has no scope watchers
- Instead of depending on knowledge of the order of controller/pre-link/post-link phases, it uses a clear message send/receive paradigm, and so I would argue is easier to understand and maintain.
- Doesn't depend on behaviour being in the pre-link function, which isn't that typical, and  you have to be mindful to not put in behaviour that modifies the DOM in it.
- Doesn't add variables to the scope hierarchy (but it does add events)

Comment: This is very like the promises solution--they both set up an external communication mechanism. This one is neater because there is no order dependency (the promise has to exist on the scope before the child `.then`s it), so I like that.

Comment: Have you ever found a clear explanation of the limits of DOM manipulation inside a pre-link? The parent directive's pre-link is telling its controller to build a giant UI component, and the child directives are doing all sorts of DOMy stuff to it. I haven't run into a blocking issue yet, but want to understand the caveats.

Comment: @SimpleAsCouldBe I realise that I don't know what you can/can't do regarding the DOM manipulation, and my searching hasn't really resulted in anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

Based on experiments, and asking correction if I am wrong, I have found Angular runs its compile phase in the following order:

```
  1. compile methods of all directives both parent and child, run in flat order
  2. parent controller
  3. parent pre-link
  4. (all actions of children directives)
  5. parent post-link (AKA regular `link` function)
```

The public gist of this experiment is here: https://gist.github.com/SimpleAsCouldBe/4197b03424bd7766cc62

With this knowledge, it seems like the `pre-link` callback on the parent directive is a perfect fit. The solution looks like this:

```
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);

    app.directive('bigPoppa', function($q){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            compile: function(scope, el) {
                return {
                    pre:  function(scope, el) {
                      console.log('bigPoppa pre');
                      scope.componentThatNeedsDom = { el: el, title: 'Something' };
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    });

    app.directive('babyBird', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, bigPoppaController){
                console.log('babyBird post-link');
                console.log('bigPoppa DOM-dependent component', scope.componentThatNeedsDom);
            }
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5G72/1/

Thanks to @runTarm and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950663/functionality-of-angular-directive-before-return-and-compile-chain) for pointing me in the `pre-link` direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 patterns that you can use to achieve what you want

- You can have code in a child linking function that reacts to changes in a parent directive's controller, by `require`ing the parent directive's controller, and creating a `$watch`er on some value in it.
- If you need run something in the parent linking function, and only then change a value in its controller, it is possible for a directive to `require` *itself*, and access the controller from the linking function.

Putting these together in your example becomes:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('bigPoppa', function($q){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'bigPoppa',
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.componentThatNeedsDom = null;
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, controller){
      controller.componentThatNeedsDom = { el: el, title: 'Something' };
    }
  }
});

app.directive('babyBird', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^bigPoppa',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, bigPoppaController){
      scope.$watch(function() {
          return bigPoppaController.componentThatNeedsDom
      }, function(componentThatNeedsDom) {
          console.log('poppa DOM component in bird linking function', componentThatNeedsDom);
      }); 
    }
  }
});
```

Which can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/4L5bj/1/ . This has the benefits over your answer that it doesn't depend on scope inheritance, and doesn't pollute the scope with values that are only used by these directives.

Comment: We both don't like the $scope solution, I'm with you there. I think I prefer a pre-link solution to your $watch on a controller property because pre-link doesn't add anything to the $digest cycle at all. The solution suggested here must run the $watch function on every $digest, even though I only ever need it for initial construction.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the directive including its own controller and using that as a communication mechanism between parent and children is something I am using and I think it's extremely effective, it just doesn't help me with timing unless I'm willing to set up a $watch.