# AngularJS : How to make directives evaluate from outside in?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

## Executable example:

http://jsbin.com/secuz/5/edit?html,js,output

## Details

The above failure contradicts my assumption about in what order Angular directives are processed. I would expect that outer directives get run first, then execution propagates inwards.

Am I correct to think that this out-of order evaluation is due to `ng-if` having higher priority than `ng-show`? And if so, shouldn't priorities only be taken into account if two directives are on the same element?

## Main question

How can I make sure execution always goes from outside in? Do I need to give the same priority to all the directives I use?

### Edit:

Tried 2 additional scenarios:

- If both are `ng-if`s, then the propagation happens from outside-in, just as expected:

`[[ '1 if', true ], [ '2 if', true ], [ '1 if', true ], [ '2 if', true ]]`

- However, two `ng-show`s exhibit a counter-intuitive behaviour:

`[[ '2 show', true ], [ '1 show', true ], [ '2 show', true ], [ '1 show', true ]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilation involves these three call-back-bindable steps:

- `compile`
- `pre-link`
- `post-link`

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144945/tell-child-directive-to-act-after-a-parent-directive-has-done-dom-actions/25145361#25145361).

I am not sure where ng-show and ng-if do their behavior, but I bet you could find out.

If ng-show and ng-if set up the behavior you're testing in the post-link, that actually executes in reverse order, climbing up from the lowest element and back out, so this would explain your finding.

Comment: Oh, so it is the post link functions that propagates from the inside out, then! Makes sense, after all. And indeed if I change `ngShow` like this: https://gist.github.com/Wizek/56e966ceae9026ae9c81, I get the expected output: `[ [ '1 show', true ], [ '2 show', true ], [ '1 show', true ], [ '2 show', true ] ]` and `[ [ '1 show', true ], [ '2 if', true ], [ '1 show', true ], [ '2 if', true ] ]`. Do you think the angular team would accept a pull request like that?

Comment: Created a PRQ either way, I think this is an improvement: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8521

Comment: I see it. [Your commit](https://github.com/Wizek/angular.js/commit/ed82385cf702d5508991a0d13d952c66d1ddd09c) makes sense. I think there are some issues with manipulating the `el` in a pre-link--might have to do with the element being a "template" at that point rather than a "real" DOM node. I don't have a full understanding. Curious to know how the PR is received.

Comment: I would be very curious as to what kind of issues it might cause, especially since all it controls is a class. No scope interactions there. Also: The "template manipulation" part you are referring to is during the compile phase, isn't it?

Comment: @Wizek my knowledge is full of FUD on this subject, I can be no help to you unfortunately.